# com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource Error

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, deployment

Tengo un servicio RESTful creado en Netbeans que se conecta a una base de datos mysql remota. En local me funciona bien el servicio, pero cuando lo desplego en el servidor Glassfish remoto me sale este error:

```
> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app
> [JerseyRESTfulService] : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse
> Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258):
> org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
> Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection.
> Cause: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for :
> com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource Error Code: 0. Please
> see server.log for more details.
```

El nombre de la clase o classpath que dice que esta mal, lo pone Netbeans automaticamente al generar el servicio. A que hace referencia? Como lo pudeo solucionar? No se realmente que valor deberia de tener. Esta en el `glassfish-resources.xml`. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Tienes el jar JDBC de MySQL agregado en Glassfish?

Comment: _It is recommended to place JDBC drivers, that are used by all the 
applications in the domain, in domain-dir/lib or 
domain-dir/lib/classes. A restart of the application server instance 
is required today so that the JDBC drivers are visible to applications 
deployed in the domain._ El jar debe estar en Glassfish, en las carpetas `domain-dir/lib` o bien en `domain-dir/lib/classes`. Reinicias el servidor y debería funcionar. Ver: https://blogs.oracle.com/sivakumart/entry/classloaders_in_glassfish_an_attempt

Comment: Muchas gracias! Tema resuelto!!

Comment: Me alegro. Si la respuesta indica la solución por favor márcala  para que no quede la pregunta abierta.

Answer (score 2):

El error parece indicar que el archivo jar de MySQL JDBC no está disponible para Glassfish.

De acuerdo a la Oracle Doc:

> It is recommended to place JDBC drivers, that are used by all the 
>   applications in the domain, in domain-dir/lib or 
>   domain-dir/lib/classes. A restart of the application server instance 
>   is required today so that the JDBC drivers are visible to applications
>   deployed in the domain.
>
> ---
>
> Se recomienda colocar los controladores JDBC, que son
>   utilizados por todas las Aplicaciones en el dominio, en
>   `domain-dir/lib` o en `domain-dir/lib/classes`. Un reinicio de la
>   instancia del servidor de aplicaciones es necesario para que los
>   controladores JDBC sean visibles para las aplicaciones.

También, existe un [plugin Maven para Glassfish](http://maven-glassfish-plugin.java.net/) que te puede servir. El uso de Maven y este complemento ayudaría a automatizar el paso de despliegue. Esto sería más robusto que hacer implementaciones manuales.