# Error in allocating a connection Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource

Tags: java, jsf

Tengo una aplicación con java server faces , estoy usando apache NetBeans 11 , glassfish 5 y tengo ese error, ¿Cómo se puede solucionar?

Comment: Este problema ya ha sido resuelto, ver solución  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56080/com-mysql-jdbc-jdbc2-optional-mysqldatasource-error

Comment: segui los pasos pero sigue sin funcionar